# How does has_module_permission work with inline models in django admin

Tags: django

While there are other ModelAdmin methods that can be used to hide inlines, it's [noted here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options) that the InlineModelAdmin also shares the `has_module_permission` feature with ModelAdmin.

It works perfectly on ModelAdmin objects as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_module_permission) but **I don't seem to understand how it works or is supposed to work** for InlineModelAdmin objects.

```
class HideModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        if condition:
            # This works as expected. Hides it from the menu items
            return False
        return super().has_module_permission(request


class HideTabularInlineModelAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        if condition:
            # This does not work as expected. The inline is visible places I don't expect to see it
            return False
        return super().has_module_permission(request
```

I am simply inheriting the above where I need them e.g

```
class SomeModelAdmin(HideModuleAdmin):
    pass

class SomeTabularInline(HideTabularInlineModelAdmin):
    pass
```